# Issue when streaming some TV channels threw ffMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, television

I am trying to stream a TV Tuner feed with ffMpeg through udp.

The ffMpeg command line I use is the following :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i udp://@239.255.255.9:1234 -map 0:p:1317:0 -profile:v baseline -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -vf scale=720:576-b:v 500k -f rtp udp://10.150.112.107:15048/ -map 0:p:1317:1 -acodec pcm_mulaw -strict experimental -ar 8k -ac 1 -b:a 128k -f rtp udp://10.150.112.107:15032/
```

Where:

- ***1317*** is the program id (channel)
- ***10.150.112.107*** is where I want to stream the TV channel
- ***239.255.255.9*** is where I receive the original TV channel's feed from my TV Tuner

My problem is that with some program IDs it is working and with some others it is not : **it is working with 1572 ("*channel 10 hd*") but not with 1317 ("*7flix Sydney*")**.

The output of this command-line for channel 1572 (where it works) is the following :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tuner Manager\ServerModule> ffmpeg.exe
 -i udp://@239.255.255.7:1234 -map 0:p:1572:0 -profile:v baseline -crf 30 -prese
t ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -vf scale=720:576 -    b:v 500k -f rtp udp://1
0.150.112.107:15048/ -map 0:p:1572:1 -acodec pcm_mulaw -strict experimental -ar
8k -ac 1 -b:a 128k -f rtp udp://10.150.112.107:15032/
ffmpeg version N-71924-ga2190de Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 37.100 / 56. 37.100
  libavformat    56. 31.102 / 56. 31.102
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[NULL @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cc980] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cdbc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cc980] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cc980] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cc980] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cdbc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cdbc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004967c80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000049ce980] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cdbc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpeg2video @ 00000000049cdbc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpeg2video @ 000000000497e3e0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0000000004975b40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknow
n: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Unknow
n: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Unknow
n: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Unknow
n: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 8 (Unknow
n: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 9 (Unknow
n: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 10 (Unkno
wn: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 14 (Unkno
wn: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 15 (Unkno
wn: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 16 (Unkno
wn: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 25 (Unkno
wn: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 26 (Unkno
wn: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 27 (Unkno
wn: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 29 (Unkno
wn: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 30 (Unkno
wn: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000494d6c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 31 (Unkno
wn: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.255.255.7:1234':
  Duration: N/A, start: 64984.698511, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1569
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ONE
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:25[0x3e8]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:26[0x3f2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:27[0x3fc]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
    Stream #0:23[0x202]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:24[0x2a0](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:7[0x241](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  Program 1573
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TEN Digital
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:14[0x3ea]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:15[0x3f4]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:16[0x3fe]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
    Stream #0:17[0x200]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:18[0x28a](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:19[0x240](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  Program 1574
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TVSN
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:6[0x206]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420
p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 5
0 tbc
    Stream #0:28[0x2b2](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:29[0x3eb]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:30[0x3f5]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:31[0x3ff]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
  Program 1575
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ONE
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:23[0x202]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:24[0x2a0](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:7[0x241](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:25[0x3e8]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:26[0x3f2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:27[0x3fc]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
  Program 1576
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ELEVEN
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:8[0x3e9]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:9[0x3f3]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:10[0x3fd]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
    Stream #0:11[0x204]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:12[0x2a9](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:13[0x242](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  Program 1577
    Metadata:
      service_name    : SpreeTV
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:0[0x208]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420
p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 5
0 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x2bc](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stere
o, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:3[0x3ec]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:4[0x3f6]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:5[0x400]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
  Program 1572
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TEN HD
      service_provider: TEN Sydney
    Stream #0:20[0x1ff]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv
, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:21[0x289](eng): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side
), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:22[0x23f](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:2[0x1fd2]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:14[0x3ea]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:15[0x3f4]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:16[0x3fe]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
[NULL @ 0000000005af6de0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

The output of this command-line for channel 1317 (where it does not works) is the following :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Administrator.TMC>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tv Tuner Mana
ger\ServerModule\ffmpeg.exe" -i udp://@239.255.255.9:1234 -map 0:p:1317:0 -profi
le:v baseline -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -vf scale=720:576
-b:v 500k -f rtp udp://10.150.112.107:15048/ -map 0:p:1317:1 -acodec pcm_mulaw -
strict experimental -ar 8k -ac 1 -b:a 128k -f rtp udp://10.150.112.107:15032/
ffmpeg version N-71924-ga2190de Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 37.100 / 56. 37.100
  libavformat    56. 31.102 / 56. 31.102
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[NULL @ 0000000004789600] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000000004789600] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000004789600] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472dac0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[NULL @ 000000000472a060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] no frame!
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472dac0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472c620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 0000000004789600] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000004789600] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000004789600] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472dac0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000472a060] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472dac0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472c620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000000000472dac0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpeg2video @ 00000000047c9200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 000000000473a8a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpegts @ 0000000004710020] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Unknow
n: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0000000004710020] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Unknow
n: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.255.255.9:1234':
  Duration: N/A, start: 77183.898689, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1312
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7 Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:0[0x201]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420
p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 14950 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 5
0 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x202](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stere
o, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x204](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1313
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7 Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:0[0x201]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420
p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 14950 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 5
0 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x202](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stere
o, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x204](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1314
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7TWO Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:18[0x221]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 14950 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:10[0x222](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x224](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1315
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7mate Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:13[0x231]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 14950 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:15[0x232](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:12[0x234](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1316
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7HD Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:6[0x241]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 19
20x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:16[0x243](eng): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, ster
eo, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:8[0x244](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1317
    Metadata:
      service_name    : 7flix Sydney
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:3[0x206]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:11[0x251]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 12500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc
    Stream #0:9[0x253](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stere
o, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:14[0x254](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
  Program 1320
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RACING.COM
      service_provider: Seven Network
    Stream #0:7[0x281]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 64
0x576 [SAR 8:5 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:17[0x282](eng): Audio: aac_latm (HE-AACv2) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011
), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:4[0x299]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
Cannot map stream #0:3 - unsupported type.
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming first two elementary streams for a program are video and audio but that might not be the case, and that is exactly what's happening here. You ended up mapping video and some unknown data stream which couldn't be transcoded.

Unfortunately it is not possible to ask ffmpeg for "first video stream of this program" - `-map` is not smart enough to parse both program specifier and stream type specifier. In your case there is only one video and one audio stream so you should be able to do the following: `-map 0:p:1317 -ignore_unknown -map -d -map -s`, i.e. map everything from the program and then remove unknown, data and subtitle tracks.